# Trying to install libopc, libxml2-dev, and zlib1g-dev

Tags: ubuntu, zlib, libxml2, libopc

I'm trying to install the above in Ubuntu.  When I tried following instructions at [libopc Linux install](https://libopc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=linux_ubuntu) by typing sudo command at step 3 at linux command prompt, it said I'm missing libxml2-dev and zlib1g-dev. When I downloaded libxml2-dev from  [libxml2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libxml2), the i386 version, and ran following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i libxml2-dev_2.7.6.dfsg-1ubuntu1.13_i386.deb
```

It said libxml2-dev:i386 depends on libxml2 ubuntu1.13, however libxml2:i386 on system is 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6. It says libxml2-dev:i386 depends on zlib1g-dev | libz-dev.

It seems like a tangled mess!  Am I installing the wrong version of libxml2?  Is there a better package to install to get libopc for Linux?

I don't have a lot of experience with installing with sudo or downloading/unzipping in ubuntu.

Update:  I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it by executing the below commands:
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev